# How to access index Lucene on Amazon S3?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, lucene

I created a bucket on S3 to share some indexes Lucene by multiple EC2 instances.
The indexes were been created in local machine and after were uploaded into the bucket.
Now I would to access these indexes from my virtual machine in EC2, but the IndexReader Lucene needs a local file directory.

In the specific I have this situation:

path index on bucket S3 -> `bucket_name/indexes/index_target_directory`

```
IndexReader indexReader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(new File(index_target_directory_path)));
AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey));
S3Object s3object = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest("bucket_name","indexes/index_target_directory"));
```

I know that `s3object.getContent()` returns an `InputStream`, how can I use it with `IndexReader`?

Comment: S3 seems like the wrong solution for a Lucene index, have you considered a network drive, e.g. EFS or SoftNAS?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No, I haven't considered this solution, because in the most of the university's courses that I  followed, I learn only the use of EC2 and S3 on AWS.
I will verify if the grant of the university has enabled the use of EFS.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [`lucene-s3directory`](https://github.com/albogdano/lucene-s3directory) which I wrote. It can **read and write** Lucene indices to/from AWS S3 directly and does not need a local filesystem. It's pretty early stage so use with caution.

```java
S3Directory dir = new S3Directory("my-lucene-index");
dir.create();
// use it in your code in place of FSDirectory, for example
dir.close();
dir.delete();
```